# Explain the last dash in a bash/pipe expression

Tags: bash, pipe

I am trying to understand a bash expression

```
oc process -f build/my-build-template.yaml  GITSERVER=$GITSERVER | oc create -f -
```

found here: https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/15474

This is an example from the OpenSift API. The first part `oc process -f build/my-build-template.yaml  GITSERVER=$GITSERVER` returns some JSON:

I understand, that this JSON will be the input for the `oc create -f <EXPECT FILE AS INPUT HERE>` which expects a file.

What is the purpose of the last `-` in the `... | oc create -f -`

Comment: It means the command after the pipeline will read from `stdin`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many tools allow specification of standard input as a filename of "-". This allows the pipe to work as expected without requiring a shell- or OS-based workaround.

Comment: It should be stressed that handling the dash is the responsibility of the tool (`oc` in this case).  Normally a tool will either specify in its man page that `-` can be given as a filename to indicate that `stdin` should be used instead of a real file, or *it will not support this dash-feature at all*.  Many tools have no special handling of `-` and will search for a file of this name then.  Then `/dev/stdin` can often be used instead (depends on the operating system then) in such cases.  Have a look at `man oc` to see whether `oc` supports this.  I don't have `oc`, so I cannot look this up.